# which of $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{13}$ or $ \sqrt{34}$ is larger?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

which of $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{13}$ or $ \sqrt{34}$ is larger?
 I tried to define $f= \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+8}+\sqrt{x+29}$ and use cslculus but have failed. please helps. Is there any non calculus solution? such as algebraic approach, thanks in advance.

Comment: Square both sides. One one side we get $18+2\sqrt{65}$, on the other we get $34$. Which is bigger?

Answer (score 12):

Note that
$$(\sqrt 5+\sqrt{13})^2=5+2\sqrt {65}+13 >5+2\cdot 8+13 =34.$$

Comment: You beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

$${\sqrt5\over\sqrt{34}-\sqrt{13}}={\sqrt{170}+\sqrt{65}\over21}\gt{\sqrt{169}+\sqrt{64}\over21}=1$$

We might add the "next" case:

$${\sqrt{8}\over\sqrt{55}-\sqrt{21}}={\sqrt{440}+\sqrt{168}\over34}\lt{\sqrt{441}+\sqrt{169}\over34}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Square both and compare
$$18 + 2\sqrt{65} \sim 34\\
\sqrt{65} \sim 8\\
65 \sim 64$$